# Delegate Example From C# In Depth Confusion

Tags: c#

I am looking at this example:

```
List<Product> products = Product. GetSampleProducts() ;
products.Sort(
    (first, second) => first.Name.CompareTo(second. Name)
) ;
foreach (Product product in products)
{
    Console. WriteLine(product) ;
}
```

What function is actually called in the API when you do that?  Does the compiler create a class which implemnents the IComparer interface?

I thought delegates were anonymous methods - Here it seems to be an anonymous interface implementation which is casuing confusion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The particular overload is [`List<T>.Sort(Comparison<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) which takes a [`Comparison<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) delegate.

Answer (score 1):

The method used here is [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) which takes a delegate (a pointer to a method) as argument (in this case [Comparison<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) which is a function with two arguments returning an integer).

Do not confuse with [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx) which takes an [IComparer<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx). Contraty to Java, C# does not support inline interface implementation (or whatever this is called).

Answer (score 0):

Delegates are not anonymous methods. Your code seems to create a [Comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) delegate to `(first, second) => first.Name.CompareTo(second. Name)` (which is, by itself, an anonymous method).